# SSRS 2008 R2 - Add Custom Template to New Report Wizard

Tags: templates, reporting-services

I created a custom SSRS template and it works if I use new item; however, most of our developers use the new report wizard. Is there a way to get customer templates to appear in that list (Ocean, Generic, Corporate, Slate, etc.)?

Thnaks

Mark

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know many of the details of what is permitted in the style definition, but the file to edit is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Business Intelligence Wizards\Reports\Styles\en\StyleTemplates.xml`

I'm surprised to see that Microsoft does acknowledge (support?) that this file can be edited:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160326(v=sql.105).aspx

> You can alter existing templates or add new ones by editing the
>   StyleTemplates.xml file in the \Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Business Intelligence Wizards\Reports\Styles\ folder, where  is the language you
>   are using (for example, if you are using the English language version
>   of Visual Studio, the folder name is "EN"). This folder is located on
>   the computer on which Report Designer is installed. NoteNote There are
>   two copies of the StyleTemplates.xml file. To modify the styles that
>   are applied through the Report Wizard, edit the file that is in the
>   folder created for the language you are using.

Comment: Thanks Jamie. Seems all you can do in this file is setthe font and color attributes. You can't define a cusom template with header and footer, etc. Useful info none the less.

Answer (score 0):

Being able to update StyleTemplates.xml was helpful, but to add default Page Headers and Footers you need to update Report.rdl

For the version of SSRS listed in the answers below, this file should be found in the following location:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\ProjectItems\ReportProject\Report.rdl

I had to make my changes in another folder, then copy the file back into this directory.

source: http://www.powerpivotblog.nl/sql-server-reporting-services-ssrs-templates-and-styles/