# SSRS Report Wizard custom template

Tags: reporting-services

Before I begin, this is more of a follow up on the question asked here: [SSRS 2008 R2 - Add Custom Template to New Report Wizard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19411967/ssrs-2008-r2-add-custom-template-to-new-report-wizard)

I have edited the StyleTemplates.xml file the way I like to set all the default colors and fonts for new reports.

I have also saved a custom Report.rdl into the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\ProjectItems\ReportProject folder.

As the original poster said, this works great if you want your custom template to be used when doing "Add -> New Item" to create a new report, but it doesn't seem to work at all for the "Add New Report" option that takes you through the report wizard.

The only thing it does for the Report Wizard is show my custom StyleTemplates.xml template, but it won't include any of the actual report elements (header footer etc.)

Is there a way to get the Report Wizard to recognize custom report templates not just fonts and colors?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research, it doesn't look like there is a way to accomplish this, currently. I think the best option here would be to create a 3rd part program that will take the xml details from SSRS and modify them.